# What does glowing Mantis Blades mean?

Tags: cyberpunk-2077

I am playing with Mantis Blades and occasionally after eliminating an enemy the blades glow with a blue hue and have blue 'code' rising from them.

[image: Mantis blades with blue glowing code]

I have no idea what this is telling me. What does this blue code glow mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to Reddit, it's one of your Relic perks that is giving you the glitch effect.
Probably *Jailbreak*, which has a synergy with *Mantis Blades*:

> Dismembering an enemy or performing a Finisher with **Mantis Blades** will charge the next Leap Attack.
> Charge an attack, and perform a long-range Leap Attack.

[image]

Check if you can perform a longer Leap Attack when having that blue effect.